# How to create a Azure Bot resource using powershell or azure cli

Tags: botframework

I need to create Azure Bot using powershell or azure cli, but so far haven't figure out how to do it.

I could manually create Azure Bot resource in Azure Portal, following this instruction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned#create-the-resource

I only found [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-bot-create) to create bot using command `az bot create`, but following this command it only could create Web App Bot or Bot Channels Registration. Based on document, these two types of bots are deprecated.

*Web App Bot and Bot Channels Registration are deprecated but existing resources will continue to work. You should use Azure Bot, instead.*

Is there any way to create Azure Bot using powershell or azure cli? Thanks!

Comment: This function is still missing today.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cuserassigned) for deploying a bot to Azure using `az cli`. Make sure you carefully read the steps and the associated notes to ensure you don't miss anything and that you enter the appropriate commands. There are commands on the page for different situations, and you need to pick the correct ones.